# jQuery ui spinner percentage calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one jquery ui spinner input where it shows values from 0% to 100% with increment of 10.
which is fine. I am trying to add some additional function.

Here is what I am wanting: In my spinner field my value can be anything from 0% to 100% and if
I start increasing or decreasing value it should display How much is remaining from the 100%.

Like if I make my value 40% in spinner than in the text beside the input field should display 60% remaining. Is this possible to make ? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

**[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FNys7/24/)**

**js**

```
$("#spinner").spinner({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 10
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="spinner"  value="0"/>
<p class="right totalResult">100% Remaining</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, one easy way would be to wrap the 100 in a span and use this jQuery:

```
$("#spinner").spinner({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 10,
    spin: function (e, ui) {
        $('p.right.totalResult span').text(100-ui.value)
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FNys7/26/)**

Comment: Excellent! This is the most easiest way to do that. Thanks! God Bless you. you made my day.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$("#spinner").spinner({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 10,
    spin: function( event, ui ) {
        var remain = 100 - ui.value;
     $(".totalResult").html(remain + "% Remaining");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FNys7/27/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an event listener for the spin(when it goes up or down).
You can do it like below:

```
$("#spinner").spinner({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 10
}).on("spin",function(event, ui){
    $(".right").text((100 - ui.value) + "% Remaining")
});
```

I hope this helps!